# Click a random radiobutton c#

Tags: c#

If button3 is clicked it should perform a click on one of the 11 radiobuttons.
This program works, but I want to know if there is any shorter way of typing this.

I want to know because I if I want to do this with 50 radiobuttons for example, then it would be a extreme long.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random RandomRadioButton = new Random();
        int Simuleer = RandomRadioButton.Next(0, 12);

        if (Simuleer == 0) { radioButton0.PerformClick(); }
        if (Simuleer == 1) { radioButton1.PerformClick(); }
        if (Simuleer == 2) { radioButton2.PerformClick(); }
        if (Simuleer == 3) { radioButton3.PerformClick(); }
        if (Simuleer == 4) { radioButton4.PerformClick(); }
        if (Simuleer == 5) { radioButton5.PerformClick(); }
        if (Simuleer == 6) { radioButton6.PerformClick(); }
        if (Simuleer == 7) { radioButton7.PerformClick(); }
        if (Simuleer == 8) { radioButton8.PerformClick(); }
        if (Simuleer == 9) { radioButton9.PerformClick(); }
        if (Simuleer == 10) { radioButton10.PerformClick(); }
        if (Simuleer == 11) { radioButton11.PerformClick(); }
    }
```

Comment: This question is more suitable for Code Review http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Create a `List<RadioButton>` called something like `rButtons` and in it store all of the radio buttons, like so `foreach(Control rb in this.Controls){if(rb is RadioButton){rButtons.Add((RadioButton)rb);}}` or if you want to be a bit more savvy, the for loop can be like this `foreach ( RadioButton rb in this.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>()) {/*code*/}`

Comment: I'm not a `C#` guy, but isn't this simply solved by just using a `for()` loop ?

Answer (score 1):

If this is `WinForms` try this:

```
string name = string.Format("radioButton{0}", Simuleer);
this.Controls/* or container that groups thease radio buttons */
             .OfType<RadioButton>().FirstOrDefault(ctrl => ctrl.Name == name).PerformClick();
```

Comment: It should be =>string name = string.Format("radioButton{0}", Simuleer);

Comment: This won't work. You can't use `OfType<>` on the result of `FirstOrDefault`. You have to apply `OfType<>` first. And then you'd better use `First` than `FirstOrDefault`. In this case the `InvalidOperationException` is better than the consquential `NullReferenceException`, because it will say what is the actual problem.

Comment: You're missing the '{0}' from your string.Format()

Comment: Thanks guys. Just made this in few seconds, now i will edit my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This is bit long but this code will be easy to maintain in the future.

Take `RadioButtonList` compare to `Separate Radio buttons`.

```
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Random random = new Random();

            var radioButtonNumber = random.Next(RadioButtonList1.Items.Count);

            RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = radioButtonNumber;

            RadioButtonListClick(radioButtonNumber);

        }

        private void RadioButtonListClick(int number)
        {
            switch (number)
            {
                case 0:
                    // Call the function realted to radio button 0 in your case.
                    break;
                    .
                    .
                    .

            }
        }
```

**Note:** This will make sure at compile time that this code will not fail at run time. as compare to making sure that the `radiobutton` id should be same and if it do not find one then it will throw run time error.